# Raspbian: chromium crashes when logged in as root

Tags: raspbian, chromium, root, bugs

I have got a clean install of Raspbian on an RPi 4B.
If I log in as root (not as the standard pi user) and try to open the Chromium web browser, by clicking its icon on the Task Bar, Chromium simply crashes and does not start. Everything works fine if I am logged in as pi. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Try starting it from the command line to see if there's more information to be had that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chromium is designed not to work when run as `root`, for security reasons. There are [workarounds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451290/how-to-run-chromium-as-root), of which currently (AFAIK) only patching the executable works, others have been fixed.

Filing a bug report about this on Chromium dev boards is a good way to get banned there. I don't share this point of view (IMO a gun should not stall just because it looks like the user is trying to shoot themselves in the foot), but Chromium team has a different opinion.